# Role based content publishing

Tags: hooks, workflows

- Content created by Role A should not be published and only moderator should be able to publish it.
- Content created by A should publish automatically.

How can this be accomplished in Drupal?

Cheers

Comment: This process is normally called "workflow" in the context of a content management system.

Answer (score 3):

That's a very broad question so I can only really give a very broad answer. There are two options that I know of for this type of workflow:

1. The aptly named [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow) module

   > The workflow module allows the creation and assignment of arbitrary workflows to Drupal node types. Workflows are made up of workflow states. For example, a workflow with the states Draft, Review, and Published could be assigned to the Story node type.
2. A combination of the [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) and [Workbench Moderation](http://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) modules

   > Workbench provides overall improvements for managing content that Drupal does not provide out of the box.
   >
   > Workbench Moderation adds arbitrary moderation states to Drupal core's "unpublished" and "published" node states, and affects the behavior of node revisions when nodes are published. Moderation states are tracked per-revision; rather than moderating nodes, Workbench Moderation moderates revisions.

Comment: Of the two, I prefer the Workbench suite.

Comment: @MPD Me too, apart from the fact that currently you have to patch the Workbench Moderation module if you want to change the default draft/published states (they're hard-coded at the moment). Small price to pay for an excellent module though

Comment: Thanks for the summary of the modules, it is now the basis for the workflow tag wiki.  BTW, I just did a D7 site w/ Workbench Moderation and was able to define all the states I wanted via the UI and attach them to transitions.

Comment: @MPD Try removing the default 'draft' state ;) `workbench_moderation_state_none()` won't work any more if you do that and you get some funky results. Good thinking updating the tag wiki

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) module to do this.  Make the necessary content type(s) subject to revisioning and then grant one role permission to publish subject to moderation and grant the other permission to publish without moderation.

Comment: great - can I use Rules module to just create a Rule .. Revisioing makes things more complex

Comment: You could try implementing something in rules but that might be more work/harder to maintain in the long run than just using the Revisioning or Workbench modules.

Comment: Totally agree with Patrick, it's probably going to be much more future-proof to use an established module to do something like this. Plus with any of those three modules you get extra features that you might end up wanting to use further down the line (e.g. integrating access rules with [Workbench Access](http://drupal.org/project/workbench_access))

Comment: The Revisioning module also has built-in Rules integration via the included sub-module.

Comment: Thanks guys ... where is the "permission to publish without moderation"? Sorry to be such a pain. Thanks